# Get max value from Access database using SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need to get the max value from a column and store it at long varibale.

My VBA code :

```vb
Private Sub ADOFromExcelToAccessDstribute()
    Dim dstibute_ID As Long

    ' get the next dstibute id
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim qry As String
        
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=W:\data\Database.accdb;jet 
    OLEDB:Database password=123;"
    qry = "SELECT Max(distributeSummeryTable.distributeID) AS MaxOfdistributeID FROM 
    distributeSummeryTable;"
    rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    
    dstibute_ID = rst.MaxOfdistributeID
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    
    'buile the export log
    exportReportPacks

    If (dstibute_ID = "" Or dstibute_ID = 0) Then
        dstibute_ID = 1
    End If

    'add data to data base
    ADOFromExcelToAccessDstributeSummeryTable (dstibute_ID)
    ADOFromExcelToAccessFulldistributeSummeryTable (dstibute_ID)
End Sub
```

This is my database table and the field I want to return
[image: database]

I get an error in my code.
Info online and at StackOverflow didn't solve my issue.
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED,

1. my syntax was wrong i should use ! insted of .
2. i try to store null value in long, it make error.
   my change was :

   ```
    If (rst!MaxOfdistributeID <> "") Then
      dstibute_ID = rst!MaxOfdistributeID
    End If
   ```